# Write console output to a .txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to write my java console output to a .txt file in my desktop.
But when that method starts, i have the console output and the txt file gets created, but it's empty and I realized that the BufferedReader (in) is not working... (Because of the "ok1 - i" statement)

The question is WHY?? or WHAT'S WRONG WITH MY CODE??
This is my code, so you can see and run it

```
   package noobxd;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.util.Random;

   public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Mario\\Desktop\\output.txt";

    generate_codes();

    writetxt(path);
}

private static void writetxt(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    try {
        String inputLine;
        inputLine = "";
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Starting");
        while (!inputLine.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("ok1"+i);
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("ok2"+i);
            out.write(inputLine);
            System.out.println("ok3"+i);
            out.newLine();
            System.out.println("ok4"+i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("Write Successful");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
    } finally {
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}

private static void generate_codes() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        int code = rnd.nextInt(201) + 100;
        int students = rnd.nextInt(31) + 40;
        int j = rnd.nextInt(4);
        String type = new String();
        switch (j) {
            case 0:
                type = "Theory";
                break;
            case 1:
                type = "Lab";
                break;
            case 2:
                type = "Practice";
                break;
            case 3:
                type = "Exam";
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("TEL" + code + "-TopicNumber" + i + "-" + students + "-" + type);

    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your time, please help me solve my problem.

Comment: +1 for the noobxd package name ;)

Comment: @UncleIroh hahah lol that's because this is an "extra app" to help me export a txt file to be used in my java-sql based app (the main one, that can import a txt file) so this is just in console then i named it noobxd

Answer (score 2):

```
String inputLine;
inputLine = "";
...
while (!inputLine.isEmpty())  // this is false and so the loop is not executed
```

In the future, please learn to use debugging tools and simply read your code more carefully. If you're trying to read until EOF, use

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: well, but if i set this to `(while(inputLine.isEmpty()))` the output is just 
...
`TEL221-TopicNumber27-55-Lab`
`TEL280-TopicNumber28-58-Practice`
`TEL174-TopicNumber29-51-Lab`
`Starting`
`ok10`

Comment: it's supposed to be like a "flag" that shows me if the method had executed properly, so with this output (just ok1 0) (first ok when line i=0(the first line)) i know that i have entered to the while statement, but the `inputLine = in.readLine()` method did not executed

Comment: @user2161991 I know what it is, but I don't know what it's supposed to be. You can't expect us to be intimately familiar with the behaviour of your program...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep looping until the user enters an empty line at the console, you probably want something like

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("ok1"+i);
        inputLine = in.readLine();
        if (inputLine.isEmpty()) 
            break;
        // the rest of your loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probable should do something like this:

```
inputLine = in.readLine();
while (inputLine != null && !inputLine.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("ok1"+i);
    System.out.println("ok2"+i);
    out.write(inputLine);
    System.out.println("ok3"+i);
    out.newLine();
    System.out.println("ok4"+i);
    i++;
    inputLine = in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: i did what you said, but still `inputLine=in.readLine();` is not executed, i don't know why